# Rails two sided value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, model

Anyone have an idea of how to create a two-sided object. E.g.
A seller selects items from a multiple select dropdown list in a form. And those items he selects are made available for another dropdown list to be selected by a buyer.

Here i'm talking about Size

The seller selects what sizes are available, then the buyer gets options out of the available sizes.

I've currently got the sizes in an array in the model

`Size_options = [XXS, XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL, 2, 4, 6, 8]`

and the dropdown list for the seller is

```
 <%= select_tag :size, Product::Size_options, multiple: true %>
```

How do i make the selected options available to the buyer?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to save the sizes to DB or somewhere so the sellers choice persists.
From there all you have to do is retrieve data from DB and populate the dropdown with it.

One way to do this will be creating a new model for sizes. Or adding a array serialized field in the `Product` model.

That way when you are rendering a page to the seller, you show `Product::Size_options` AND select which ones are available from the database. (Check API, should be easy to implement)

And on user side, you render sizes only from the database

If you create models, they would look something like this:

```
Products       ProductSizes          Sizes
  - id           - product_id         - id
  - name         - size_id            - code('M', 'S')
```

Comment: If i create a model for Sizes, i'm assuming what you mean is each column would be a specific size? Or how does this work?